# How to export file from Ubuntu in WSL to my Windows 11?

Tags: 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I'm trying to figure out a way to do it before I do my homework. I have been searching for a while and found no solution.

This is in Ubuntu:

[image: This is in Ubuntu]

For example, if this is my homework file how do I export it to here?

[image: This is where I want this file in Ubuntu to go to]

I installed this Ubuntu on WSL on Windows 11.

Comment: Please add some details. Are the two systems connected in any way? Are you running Ubuntu under Windows? Or is this a dual boot computer? Or are they different systems on the same network? Would a simple USB stick work here?

Comment: @Jos I'm sorry. I just edited it. I downloaded it from Microsoft Store on Windows 11 using it like a command prompt on Windows 11

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/824924/ubuntu-windows-shared-folder-using-wsl

Comment: `cp Hello.l /mnt/c/wherever/` as explained above.

Comment: I can't seem to find lxss or mnt in there even though I search it in searchbar.
@EODCraftStaff

Comment: @user68186 Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the Windows 11 File Explorer.
2. In the address bar, type `\\wsl$` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will open an access window to WSL, where you can access the file system of your WSL distribution.
3. Locate the files or folders you want to export, then copy and paste them into the Windows file system.

Comment: Thanks! I seem to able to do it if I type like the first answer of this question.
[https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1185033/what-is-the-home-directory-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

Comment: Thank you! Discovered I had 2 Ubuntu's installed!